# What is the complexity of calling .end() on a vector?

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end says the complexity is constant.

I cannot find any mention of that in the standard. Can somebody point me to the appropriate section? Or does it simply follow from other performance requirements for std::vector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complexity is indeed constant. This is stated in Table 96 from **[container.requirements.general]**, or **23.2.1 General container requirements** in the C++11 standard, and  **Table 65—Container requirements**, or **[lib.container.requirements]** in the C++03 standard.

Comment: **[lib.container.requirements]**, in case the OP is reading a standard version with different section numbering ;)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth strange, my version doesn't have the **lib**.

Comment: Interesting!  My assumption was that the **[]** section naming was unambiguous between revisions of the standard.  I no longer hold that assumption...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Mine too. I don't have the official C++11 standard though, just the very last draft to come out before ratification. Anyway, I added the C++03 references.